# Custom Payload on DialogFlow to get Kik Developer Bots to Send Videos?

Tags: json, bots, dialogflow-es, payload, kik

I'm having problems writing a custom payload on DialogFlow to get a Kik bot to send video's. I wrote my own custom payload, but will not send no matter where the videourl is coming from. Here's what I already have:

```
{
  "kik": {
    "type": "video",
    "videoUrl": "https://6oifeq.bn.files.1drv.com/y4m2tTfznJjwSNUR5OknxluI1LUdv5-EFVdpSNDNouEaEEA6ftWVOBoJ20jsrln7xXb0BrUZ_PC2EuUSCVq1l4P2h1z3TbZLD2vqvCmNY0ebgwUTVRrvF5qyvQ6eUJbvIgPlTtQW6rHcIDDl4IU5lqCw62kBfFv2R4j7zYgV6fz-aev4jXqgivj6QR5MrcelkeZ/5fcf21c1-b250-4366-9810-3f98c716026a.mp4?psid=1?",
    "video-should-be-muted":false
  }
}
```

Using Dialog Flow to send Videos on Kik with a custom payload.

Answer (score 0):

The custom payload on Dialog Flow to send videos on Kik is solved. Follow this format:

```
  "kik": {
    "type": "video",
    "videoUrl": "https://6oifeq.bn.files.1drv.com/y4mPnHGxDM_GoQ4oo9nEBx27nqrnfA3H_uRQPY0m2WI91qoPy75o1Y3RHpV3TXta_CM3mMpWpP20VzEmUS9_ruiEmrU7c8G15oclWBH7BmfZgzPoa38B63pT86RdJOkv8V9FvEIu4wYjGiyzE0IZT4nWhlIL9bE4T2wgDzBf7U5haulPNTBBH8DkLY7_MzkL0iu/5fcf21c1-b250-4366-9810-3f98c716026a.mp4?psid=1?",
    "autoplay": true
  }
}
```